# Refactoring with createSlice reduxtoolkit

Tags: redux, redux-toolkit, redux-reducers, redux-actions

I'm having trouble refactoring with createSlice, I'm a beginner with redux-toolkit and have looked through the documentation but still having problems.if someone could point me in the right direction that would be fantastic. This is the working code

```
const SET_ALERT = 'setAlert';
const REMOVE_ALERT = 'alertRemoved';

export const setAlert =
  (msg, alertType, timeout = 5000) =>
  (dispatch) => {
    const id = nanoid();
    dispatch({
      type: SET_ALERT,
      payload: { msg, alertType, id },
    });

    setTimeout(() => dispatch({ type: REMOVE_ALERT, payload: id }), timeout);
  };

const initialState = [];

export default function alertReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  const { type, payload } = action;

  switch (type) {
    case SET_ALERT:
      return [...state, payload];
    case REMOVE_ALERT:
      return state.filter((alert) => alert.id !== payload);
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current `setAlert` action creator creates a thunk action (an action which takes `dispatch` as an argument) so it cannot be an action creator that is automatically generated by `createSlice`.

---

#### createSlice

You can keep the setup very similar to what you have now.  You would have two separate actions for setting and removing an alert and a thunk for dispatching both.  The underlying basic actions *can* be created with `createSlice`.

```
import { createSlice, nanoid } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const slice = createSlice({
  name: "alerts",
  initialState: [],
  reducers: {
    addAlert: (state, action) => {
      // modify the draft state and return nothing
      state.push(action.payload);
    },
    removeAlert: (state, action) => {
      // replace the entire slice state
      return state.filter((alert) => alert.id !== action.payload);
    }
  }
});

const { addAlert, removeAlert } = slice.actions;

export default slice.reducer;

export const setAlert = (msg, alertType, timeout = 5000) =>
  (dispatch) => {
    const id = nanoid();
    dispatch(addAlert({ msg, alertType, id }));

    setTimeout(() => dispatch(removeAlert(id)), timeout);
  };
```

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/redux-toolkit-alerts-with-createslice-35wq5?file=/src/store/slice.ts:0-943)

---

#### createAsyncThunk

This next section is totally unnecessary and overly "tricky".

We can make use of `createAsyncThunk` if we consider opening the alert as the 'pending' action and dismissing the alert as the 'fulfilled' action.  It only gets a single argument, so you would need to pass the `msg`, `alertType`, and `timeout` as properties of an object.  You can use the unique id of the thunk which is `action.meta.requestId` rather than creating your own id.  You can also access the arguments of the action via `action.meta.arg`.

You can still use `createSlice` if you want, though there's no advantage over `createReducer` unless you have other actions.  You would respond to both of the thunk actions using the `extraReducers` property rather than `reducers`.

```
import { createAsyncThunk, createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

export const handleAlert = createAsyncThunk( "alert/set", (arg) => {
  const { timeout = 5000 } = arg;
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve(), timeout);
  });
});

export default createReducer(initialState, (builder) =>
  builder
    .addCase(handleAlert.pending, (state, action) => {
      const { alertType, msg } = action.meta.arg;
      const id = action.meta.requestId;
      // modify the draft state and don't return anything
      state.push({ alertType, msg, id });
    })
    .addCase(handleAlert.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
      const id = action.meta.requestId;
      // we are replacing the entire state, so we return the new value
      return state.filter((alert) => alert.id !== id);
    })
);
```

example component

```
import { handleAlert } from "../store/slice";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "../store";

export const App = () => {
  const alerts = useSelector((state) => state.alerts);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  return (
    <div>
      {alerts.map((alert) => (
        <div key={alert.id}>
          <strong>{alert.alertType}</strong>
          <span>{alert.msg}</span>
        </div>
      ))}
      <div>
        <button
          onClick={() =>
            dispatch(
              handleAlert({
                alertType: "success",
                msg: "action was completed successfully",
                timeout: 2000
              })
            )
          }
        >
          Success
        </button>
        <button
          onClick={() =>
            dispatch(
              handleAlert({
                alertType: "warning",
                msg: "action not permitted"
              })
            )
          }
        >
          Warning
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/redux-toolkit-alerts-with-createasyncthunk-2s9nc?file=/src/store/slice.ts)